# Bootstrap or Jquery Mobile for Mobile website

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile

I am planning to do a mobile website. Means it will be targeted only for only mobile phones, not tablets or PCs. I want it to have good performance (high speed).

I want to know whether I should use Bootstrap 3 or JQuery Mobile. Also I am using AngularJS. Which will serve my purpose in a cleaner way and more friendly with AngularJS. Any suggestions ??

Comment: I've used both Bootstrap and jQuery Mobile and jQuery Mobile is the easiest, quickest and requires the least amount of bandwidth because images aren't big. You can see one site I made that redirects you if you have a mobile phone. metaboup.com.

Comment: I know JQuery mobile is easy but I want to know whether Angular will fit into it so I can have a solid structure which well built.

Comment: It's just HTML CSS and jQuery libraries, why not?